# Object exported from Sketchup doesn't show properly

Tags: sketchup

I've created a simple mobile in Sketchup. I've exported it as object and then I've tried to open it with 3D Builder. However it doesn't show properly. The first problem is the png image which I've added to the model in Sketchup, the second 2 letters (M and N as you'll see below). In the program there aren't problems. Furthermore colours seem different.

Here is a screenshot of the bug:
 [image: https://snag.gy/eg8WFs.jpg]

Here is the mobile in Sketchup:

[image]
How can I fix it?

Comment: When you say "exported as object," do you mean as .OBJ file? Are you aware that SketchUp creates non-manifold 3D objects which do not meet certain standards for 3D objects typically used by other 3D compatible software?

Comment: @fred_dot_u yes as obj

Answer (score 2):

There are a few programs available which will pinpoint and sometimes repair damaged 3D model files. One program is Meshmixer which has an Analysis/Inspector feature. It accepts .OBJ files and will display failure points of the model.

[image: meshmixer inspector image]

In the image above, you can see the "alerts" presented to the user. This is a model of a different type than yours and may be more easily repaired by using the Auto Repair feature. I have had some experience with SketchUp models in Meshmixer and the Auto Repair will remove entire planar segments.

There are other 3D model repair resources, some online-based, but I expect that all of them will damage your model, based on the source application.

The most optimum method of "repair" would be to rebuild the model in a more suitable application. So many options are available in that area of software. Fusion 360 comes to mind, as it supports very well your type of design. Meshmixer would create such a model, but it would be more difficult.

You could repair manually your model with Blender, but the learning curve is quite steep for that program.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth looking at [OnShape](https://www.onshape.com/) for this kind of thing: free, very powerful, easy and with excellent import-export functions. Learning curve is also steep, but I found it a pretty easy jump, coming from another 3D CAD field (architectural to engineering - honestly quite different) so worth a look.